# How to alter CSS based on whether a form field is valid or not

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, error-handling

I have a simple form that can display 2 error codes at once, but I need only one to display (see below). #1 should be the only one displayed if user enters an **invalid** email , invalidity is determined by the form input text `required pattern=...`. Error #2 should be the only visible error if the email **is** valid. It is produced from a PHP result - this PHP file is called on via ajax within the form's html file and returns a result which is displayed as error #2.

[image]

**My question:** how do I apply an IF statement or similar, to determine whether 
the form's input field's pattern is satisfied or not. If it is unsatisfied (invalid) then perhaps we could make it's font-size 0px by altering it's CSS somehow, which would make only #2 visible. If it is satisfied, then we could continue to hide error #2's div somehow.

Here is the form (with error #2's hidden div "formResponse"):

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" class="login" action="#">
    <input name="emailaddy" id="emailaddy" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="My Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~)" required title="Invalid Email"/>
       <div id="formResponse" style="display: none;"></div>
       <button type="submit" name="loginsubmit" class="loginbutton">Login</button>

</form>
```

and the css:

```
 div.error, div.error-list, label.error, input.error, select.error, textarea.error {
      color: #D95C5C!important;
      border-color: #D95C5C!important;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
```

**Updated AJAX (via reggie's answer)** - NOTE: I don't think `if(ema == null || ema == '')` is working, because even if the user enters gibberish it still displays *both* errors. But if I change it to `if(ema == 'a')`, it properly hides `formResponse` div and only shows label.error. I need it to hide `formResponse` if the field is invalid/null - but null doesn't seem to work.  Also, the `else` function doesn't work, meaning the `label.error` div won't hide for some reason. Perhaps `null` should be replaced with a regular expression check?

**UPDATED AJAX:**   Why is it treating "hello@example.com" as null?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login/login.php",
                dataType:"text",
                data: {email: $('#emailaddy').val(), loginsubmit: 'yes'},
                success:function(result){   
                    if(result === "redirect"){
                      window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/login/private.php");
                    }
                else{
                       //var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
                       var email = $('#emailaddy').val();
                       var pattern = ".+\\@@.+\\..+";
                       var valid = email.match(pattern);
                       alert(valid);
                           if (valid == null) {
                                               } 
                        else {
                        $("#formResponse").html("That email address is not registered.").show();
                             } 
                    }
                                     }
            })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please re-describe your problem, keeping in mind the reader has no idea what Error #1 and #2 are. The image is useful - explain it a little more clearly, please. Also, do you have any code for the regex pattern matching, or do you need help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ajax, you could check the email and stop it from going to the server if invalid:

```
var ema = $('#useremail').val();      

if(ema == null || ema == '' //or whatever)         
{
$('.error1').show();
$('.error1').html('Nope');
$('.error2').hide();

return;
}
else{
//continue with ajax
```

Then handle any errors coming back from php like:

```
success: function(responseText) { 
if(responseText == "1") {
    $('.error1').hide();
$('.error2').show();

$('.error2').html(//the error msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks reggie, I'm not really sure what $('.error1').show();
$('.error1').html('Nope');
$('.error2').hide(); does though. Or really how to integrate this into my code... I'll try to figure it out in the morning and will report back

Comment: error1 and error2 are just examples of whatever class names you want to make your error divs.  The gist of it is that you can control what to show or hide right inside you ajax code.

Comment: Thanks reggie, I think you're on the right track. I've incluced my current ajax at the bottom of my question, could you please take a look?  Thank you

Comment: Getting there.  Make sure the regex check or whatever condition you use is first, then you can check it, and proceed only if valid.  So use an exclamation point, like:  if (!re.test(email)) { //then stop} else {//continue ajax...}  Also style both error divs display:none so they wont show up until told to.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it lead me to my solution. I posted my own answer to display the code easily. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: It looks like you might want to check valid email before server response, like right after e.preventDefault();  If not valid, stop, else { proceed...  But I'm glad it is working!  And glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN USE INVALID PSEUDO CLASS :

```
input[type=email]:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

here is a bunch a css validation pseudo class you can use :

```
input:valid { ... }
input:invalid { ... }
input:required,
input[aria-required="true"] { ... }
input:optional { ... }
input:out-of-range { ... }
input:in-range { ... }
```

Here is an exmple I made it for you, try to type an invalid email and you'll see the magic :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdh3qbr9/2/)**

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused as to how this will make error #2 disappear if the user enters an invalid email. It seems to address input type 'email' only, not "formResponse" .Can you provide an example? Thank you

Comment: hang on I'll try to provide an example !

Comment: Wow thanks for that, I'm going to have to implement it tomorrow though. I'll be sure to give credit where due.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my problem by following reggie's lead, and adapting it to fit my code as such:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login/login.php",
                dataType:"text",
                data: {email: $('#emailaddy').val(), loginsubmit: 'yes'},
                success:function(result){   
                    if(result === "redirect"){
                      window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/login/private.php");
                    }
                else{
                       //var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
                       var email = $('#emailaddy').val();
                      if(email.match(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/)) { 
                      $("#formResponse").html("That email address is not registered.").show();
                                               } 
                        else {

                             } 
                    }
                                     }
            })
    });
});
</script>
```

It only shows error #2 (formResponse) if the email **is valid** but not registered.